# Should there be a mathlib tag for Lean?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [already a number of questions](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathlib) that are specifically about the monolithic math library `mathlib` created in Lean.  Should we have these kinds of tags specific to particular proof solvers?  Should we a `mathlib` or `lean-mathlib` tag?

Comment: `lean-mathlib` seems like a good idea (and I noticed that there seemed to be some reasonable justifications for this on the Zulip chat).  Thanks for going forward and making the tag. We can edit it later if necessary! @GuyCoder

Answer (score 6):

I think it makes a lot of sense to have tags for particular libraries in addition to particular proof assistants.  This should be particularly useful for proof assistants that have many different libraries, but it should also apply to Lean, helping to distinguish questions about Lean itself from questions about the library design.

Comment: I would suggest only a single tag `lean-mathlib`, since I don't expect that separate mathlibs for Lean 3 and Lean 4 will be maintained and developed -- I was under the impression that once Lean 4 is stable, the entire mathlib will be ported to it and effort will shift to the new version.